# I want to customze menu_tree output

Tags: 6, routes, theming

I found a code in drupal page in this url http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/6#comment-1073

code is

```
<?php
function phptemplate_menu_tree($tree,$menu_name="") {
     return '<ul class="menu menu-$menu_name ">'. $tree .'</ul>';
}
?>
```

it is written that we can customize every menu by css and also adding $menu_name.

but even though that I have added this function into my template.php and it is working , $menu_name variable is always **empty**

really the target that I am following is :
I want to modify the css class of the ROOT us base on menu name.

for example for primary links , i want to have this return out put

```
'<ul class="menu menu-primary-links ">'. $tree .'</ul>'
```

or for secondary links i want to have this return output

```
'<ul class="menu menu-secondary-links ">'. $tree .'</ul>'
```

$tree includes all nested li items from the selected menu.

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**page.tpl.php**

for admin menu

```
    <?php print '<ul id="nav-admin" class="menu   clearfix">'.menu_tree($menu_name = 'navigation').'</ul>';?>

//for primary menu
 <?php print  '<ul id="nav-primary" class="menu clearfix">'.menu_tree($menu_name = 'primary-links').'</ul>'; ?>
//for secondary menu
 <?php print  '<ul id="nav-secondary" class="menu clearfix">'.menu_tree($menu_name = 'secondry-links').'</ul>'; ?>
```

**template.php**

> function menu_tree($tree}{return $tree;}

Comment: page.tpl.php
for admin menu
<?php print '<ul id="nav-admin" class="menu clearfix">'.menu_tree($menu_name = 'navigation').'</ul>';?>
 
//for primary menu
 <?php print  '<ul id="nav-primary" class="menu clearfix">'.menu_tree($menu_name = 'primary-links').'</ul>'; ?>
//for secondary menu
 <?php print  '<ul id="nav-secondary" class="menu clearfix">'.menu_tree($menu_name = 'secondry-links').'</ul>'; ?>

template.php
function menu_tree($tree}{return $tree;}

Answer (score 0):

Try out by calling

```
<?php print theme('links', $primary_links, array('class' =>'menu-primary-links')); ?>
```

to include primary links to the required template file. No need for phptemplate_menu_tree function in template.php

Comment: I know this function. but this function doesn't render the whole tree structure. I mean this function doesn't load nested ul that is located inside the LI tags - only the level 0 is appeared when we use theme function.